# Why can't I click on a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

I would like to use tkinter with plotting. But I just want to click on a button and read the location of the file but I can't click on a file, I don't know at all where is the problem ? Here is my code :

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

figure, ax1 = plt.subplots()

class Index(object):
    def next(self,event):
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.withdraw()
        file_name = askopenfilename()
        print(file_name)

callback = Index()
axnext = plt.axes([0.11,0.9,0.1,0.075])
bnext = Button(axnext, 'Open')
bnext.on_clicked(callback.next)

plt.show()
```

I don't understand when I click on Open I can't select file it is like the click was disabled.

Comment: Porting the imports to python2 (`import Tkinter as tk;
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename`) this works fine for me. So maybe it's a python3/tkinter related thing?

Comment: indeed it works with python 2.7 but not with Python 3 but I don't see where is the problem ? it is really strange !

Comment: Works in python2 and python3 for me. Maybe it's an OS thing? I'm working in Linux Mint; python3.4.

Comment: I have tried your code and I have not had any problems

Comment: I think the problem is part of your OS, you could add that description to your problem.